# Toggle 0 and 1 as boolean values in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a toggle component in **React** and send the state to my database using `LARAVEL`.

When I'm sending the state of the toggle, in the database it's **registered as 1 or 0**, but when I'm activating/disabling the toggle, in the `console.log` it shows the values of `true` & `false`.

The problem here is that when I send the value to the database and I want to get it, the toggle doesn't recognize 0 and 1 because I'm writing a condition for `if true` or `false`, so I can't read the values registered on the db which are 0/1.

**Is there a solution on how can I convert the received boolean to true/false ?**

**The hook and Handler :**

```
const [showlogo, setshowlogo] = useState('');

const HideLogo = () => {
    setshowlogo(!showlogo);
    console.log(showlogo)        
  }
```

**The toggle code :**

```
 <div onClick={HideLogo} >Toggle</div>
 <div className={`${ showlogo ? "on" : "off"   }`}>Valeur of logo</div>
```

Comment: @AjeetShah I did as you said like this  `<div className={`${ String(showlogo) ? "on" : "off"   }`}>Valeur of logo</div>` and `false` and it still shows 0/1.

Comment: @AjeetShah It could be but I doubt so. I'm using Laravel btw. When I'm sending the value true/false, in the database it registers 0/1, so when I want to get the values it doesn't display true/false because it registered as 0/1.

Comment: @AjeetShah MySQL. Actually as I'm searching I think Laravel is theproblem. It converts true/falseto boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other answers recommended using Boolean, but since your db returns 1 or 0, and sounds like you have no control over it, then alternative use `===` operator

```
showLogo === 1 ? 'on' : 'off'
```

and use the following to toggle between 1 and 0

```
setShowLogo( showLogo === 1 ? 0 : 1 )
```

```js
const status = 0

console.log(Boolean(status === 0))
console.log(Boolean(status === 1))

// IF it's a string then use String

const stringStatus = '0'

console.log(Boolean(stringStatus === '0'))
console.log(Boolean(stringStatus === '1'))
```

Comment: Your answer is true, in the console it show right 0 or 1 instead of true/false, but somehow `showLogo === 1 ? 'on' : 'off'` doesn't seem to work. I may try something but your solution is correct.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to toggle `0` and `1` as boolean values:

```js
const { useState } = React
const response = {data: {showlogo: 0}}

function App() {
  
  const [showlogo, setShowlogo] = useState(response.data.showlogo);

  const hideLogo = () => {
    setShowlogo(prev => prev === 0 ? 1 : 0); // <-- HERE
  }

  return (<div>
     <div onClick={hideLogo} >Toggle (click), showlogo: {showlogo}</div>
     <div className={showlogo===1?"on":"off"}> Valeur of logo</div>
  </div>)
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes the data now is indeed 0/1 instead of true false. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial value should be boolean

```
import React from "react";
let count = 1;
export default function App() {
  const [showlogo, setshowlogo] = React.useState(0);

  const HideLogo = (id) => {
    if (id % 2 !== 0) setshowlogo(1);
    else setshowlogo(0);
    count++;
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => HideLogo(count)}>Toggle</button>
      {showlogo && (
        <div className={`${showlogo ? "on" : "off"}`}>Valeur of logo</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-minsky-ljku4)

Just pass your id received from DB

```
onClick={() => HideLogo(ID)}
```

and toggle here based on passed ID

```
const HideLogo = (id) => {
   if (id=== 0) setshowlogo(1);
   else setshowlogo(0);
  };
```

Comment: In the console it shows true/false, I would want 0/1. So when `showlogo` receives 1 from the database it's true.

Comment: @AlyaKra  Can you try now ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are dealing with 1 and 0 coming from the database, you can cast them to boolean with `Boolean(x)` -

```
Boolean(0) // false
Boolean(1) // true
```

and then if you have to save them again as 0 or 1, convert them back to a number from a boolean -

```
const x = showLogo ? 1 : 0
// then send x back to the db
```

Comment: Where whould I cast them ? Inside the handler ?

Comment: wherever you are receiving them as 0 and 1, its not clear from your code where you are fetching them from the db

Comment: I'm receiving them using axios simply like this   `setshowlogo(response.data.showlogo);` .In the database it's registred as 0/1. Now that I'm searching, I found that Laravel have this problem.

Comment: to be honest, it sounds like you have a different issue, as 0 and 1 get treated as falsey and truthy values, so it would work without casting them